# How do I send the product title to contact form?

Tags: php, magento

Im currently altering the add-to links on the product page so that when a user clicks this link

```
$_product = $this->getProduct(); 
$sampleAttributes = $_product->getsample_attributes();
$id_product = $_product->getName(); //product name

<a href="http://www.sample.com/request-callback?id='<?php echo $id_product; ?>'" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Request a Callback') ?></a>
```

It will send the product name to www.sample.com/request-callback?id=''

and on the request-callback page I have

```
$id_product = intval($_GET['id']);

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id_product; ?>" name="productname"/>
```

and its half working the product name from the magento product gets inserted into the address bar but when I try and pull it from the address bar with

```
$id_product = intval($_GET['id']);
```

I get ' 0 '

any reason why this could be happening ?

Comment: `intval` expects an integar, `product name` sounds like a string.

Comment: so what would a string be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you get productName not productId.

I don't use Magento but I think it should be $id_product = $_product->getId();

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ideally I need the name of the product rather then the product ID

Comment: You can remove **intval()** function from `$id_product = intval($_GET['id']);`

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, `intval` expects an integar, if you are sending a string, remove that (and add `isset` for good messure):

```
$id_product = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:'none';
```

I would also consider renaming `id` to `name` for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 0):

I changed the $id to the product ID then used this

```
$productid = intval($_GET['id']);
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
$_product = $model->load($productid); //getting product object for particular product id
$product_name = $_product->getName();
$id_product = $product_name;
```

to retrieve the product name from the product ID.